# how read a .C file ( from wavtoccode software)?

Tags: c, wav

Convert or read a .C to wav

Hello,

for an IRL game (like an escape game) I want my players to find a .c file (i did it with WavToCode) and find a way to play it to hear the original Wav file.
How can I do?

Is there software for this?

Or another best way to read/convert file (.txt,.hex, etc) to audio ?

thank you

Comment: How do you even read C out loud? Forget the computerized approach for a second.

Comment: Maybe something like that? https://www.naturalreaders.com/software.html
They support .txt files. I've just googled. I have not tried this software.

Answer (score -1):

Use https://speechify.com/text-to-speech-online

Example:

```
char *duplicateString(const char *str)
{
    char *newstring = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
    if(newstring) strcpy(newstring, str);
    return newstring;
}
```

https://storage.googleapis.com/speechify-soundbite.appspot.com/audio/23d03d95cdd74d52cd96ba79b565522cd2d9909ef903a79bef3dc65a51ce365e.mp3?cb=1668103054800